# SpeedList in custom audio player

Tags: javascript, html

Just first speed is working
and the other tracks works with first icon’s speed list!
You know how to fix it to work each speedList for each track!?

```js
const speedlist = document.getElementById("speedlist");
speedlist.addEventListener("change", changeSpeed);

function changeSpeed(event) {
  audio.playbackRate = event.target.value;

}
```

```css
.audio-player #speedlist {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  left: 1.5rem;
  top: 0.1rem;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  background-image: url("icon/speed.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 3px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: auto;
}
```

```html
<select id="speedlist">
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
  <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use a class.

Comment: Hi, thanks but not working!